# Using different colors in Gnuplot based on a CSV file column value

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a CSV file with the following structure:

```
X,Y,Z
```

where X and Y are coordinates on a square plot and Z can be 0/1. I want to plot points with different color, depending on the value in the Z column.

Is that possible?

So far I have a file which just displays all the data on the square chart and colors them with only 1 color:

```
filename='test.csv'
set datafile separator ","
set title filename 
set size square
plot filename using 0:1 linecolor rgb "yellow"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the documentation, check `help rgbcolor variable` :

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r) + 256 * int(g) + int(b)
color1=rgb(255,0,0); color2=rgb(0,255,0)
plot fname using 1:2:($3==0?color1:color2) w p lc rgb variable
```